# Several terminal commands in one exec function

Tags: c++, unix, ubuntu, exec, fork

Just out of curiosity I am wondering what would be the easiest way to execute two or more Linux commands with. Let's take the following example:

```
1) free > tmp1
2) uptime > tmp2
3) cat tmp1 tmp2 > result
4) rm tmp1 tmp2
```

How we can achieve the same in terminal with 1 line:

```
free > tmp1 && uptime > tmp2 && cat tmp1 tmp2 > result && rm tmp1 tmp2
```

Now I have tried to achieve the same in C++ (the goal being doing it in one execlp) for instance:

```
pid_t child;
child = fork();
if ( child > 0 ) {
execlp("free", "free", ">", "tmp1", "&&", "uptime", "uptime", ">", "tmp2", "cat", "cat", "tmp1", "tmp2", ">", "result", "&&", "rm", "rm", "tmp1", "tmp2", NULL);
}
```

You get the picture I suppose. Needless to say it did not work, it just executes the first command then dies. Anyway on to the point.

Is it really necessary to create separate execlp lines inside a forked process and then to "flush" the child processes in a loop? Or do we have alternatives to do the same in a single execlp line?

If possible, please leave an example of how we could achieve the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use more than one `execlp`? Also, are you sure that `>` works in `execlp` in the first place?

Comment: There is really no specific reason, I just want to explore the options. No I am not sure at all, that is why I am asking. Still learning.

Comment: little optimization: "free > result && uptime >> result"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing "executing a program" and "entering text in your system's command interpreter". Your interpreter knows what to do with `">"` and `"&&"`, but they're not programs that can be executed.

Try using [`system()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

```
system("free > tmp1 && uptime > tmp2 && cat tmp1 tmp2 > result && rm tmp1 tmp2");
```